# How to migrate restful-authentcation to devise in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a old app with `rails 2.3.8` . Here plugin `restful-authentication` is used .

The tables are being organized for the restful authentication.

The old project is going to remake in new rails version `Rails 4.0` .

So we need to migrate previous records from old db to new db .

But the `gem restful-authentication` is not working in rails 4.0 .

Working in devise will not work for the old records .

What should be the best way to solve this issue ?

Thanks a lot